# How to run multipe WCF services using the same IIS Express instance through VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, iis-express

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 with multiple WCF service projects, which I would like to run under IIS Express as a single site with a subfolder containing each WCF project:

```
Web site
   /WCF-project1
   /WCF-project2
   /WCF-project3
```

I reckon I need to configure each project (Project->Properties->Web->Servers) in Visual Studio 2010 as well as the IIS Express configuration (applicationhost.config) ... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Web Application in Visual Studio (I named it as 'RootApp')
2. Configure it to use 'IIS Express'
3. Now open applicationhost.config file (%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config)
4. Locate the WWeb Application created in step1 ('RootApp') and edit as shown below.

   ```
       <site name="RootApp" id="123">
           <application path="/" >
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="Root app path" />
           </application>
           <application path="/app1" >
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="wcf project1 path" />
           </application>
           <application path="/app2" >
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="wcf project2 path" />
           </application>
           <application path="/app3" >
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="wcf project3 path" />
           </application>
           <application path="/app4" >
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="wcf project4 path" />
           </application>
           <bindings>
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57366:localhost" />
           </bindings>
       </site>
   ```

Comment: How do I configure each of my wcfprojects (1 .. 4) in VS 2010 (Project->Properties->Web page)?

Comment: It works perfect - thanks vikomall. Actually, I found out that you can configure the Project Url as http://localhost:8080/wcfproject1 and http://localhost:8080/wcfproject2 and only one instance will be started